# Duplicate entry and Zip exception in android studio, gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'


    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hotel"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.gson'
    }
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.gson'
    }
    compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.gson'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.gson'
    }

    compile files('libs/Guest Helper.jar')
    compile files('libs/OKSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobilekeys-android-api-deliverable-5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobilekeys-android-api-deliverable-soft-5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/idconnect.jar')
    compile files('libs/Guest.jar')
}
```

Error :

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk410Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.085 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: did this also happens after a clean build ?

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO  When try to build, the build is successful, when trying to run then this is happening, build failed. will you please tell be how to exclude something from a jar file

Comment: what gradle tasks did you mean with build and run ? have you tried a clean before run ?

Comment: Yes i also tried clean before running. when i clean the build is successful, but when  click on run, it gives the error. Do you know how to exclude a group from a jar file. although , Thank you for your interest, i really appreciate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the libraries i am using was containing the google GSON package and when i  am trying to run the build  , it shows me error of duplicate entry. Then i used a tool called JarSplice to merge both of the libraries into one, and while merging this tool remove the duplicate items and create a standalone Jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Adding the following to the `buildTypes` section fixed it for me.

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```